# Distance times Velocity

Tags: kinematics, velocity, dimensional-analysis, distance

Is there a meaningful physical concept of $distance * velocity$?

Came across something analogous in computer science and was wondering if there was any physical analogue.

Comment: In units this can be transformed to [mechanical-power/acceleration]  = $m^2/s$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [diffusion equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_equation), the diffusion coefficient typically has a dimensionality of $\mathrm{L^2T^{-1}}$.

For instance, the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) is typically written in this form:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\alpha\nabla u=0,
$$

where $u$ is temperature and $\alpha$ is the [thermal diffusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_diffusivity). The thermal diffusivity is defined as:

$$
\alpha=\frac{k}{\rho c_p},
$$

where $k$ is the thermal conductivity of the medium, $\rho$ is the mass density and $c_p$ is the specific heat capacity. The SI unit of thermal diffusivity is $\mathrm{m^2/s}$.

Comment: Although this does have the _dimensionality_ of $distance*time$ you didn't really explain if there's an actual physical analogue.  You gave a dimensional analogue, I don't see that as the same thing.  Your answer doesn't seem to address distance or time specifically.

Comment: @JMac I sort of see your point (although I think you mean $distance*velocity$). I think there is a "physical analogue" in the sense you mean, but it may seem a little contrived. We also only know that OP wants an analogue to a quantity that is a distance multiplied with a velocity. We don't know what the distance or the velocity represent or why it's meaningful to multiply them. Without more information I think there isn't much point in going further than dimension analysis to check for analogousness.

Answer (score 2):

Angular momentum for a unit mass. Angular momentum is:
$$ L= r × (mv) $$

Answer (score 1):

This could also be thought of as an "area speed" (in lack of a better word). For instance if you are painting a wall and $d$ is the width of your brush, and $v$ is the speed you are moving the brush with, the area you would cover per unit time would be $d\cdot v$. I wouldn't say that this is a commonly used physical quantity though.

Answer (score 0):

In fluid dynamics, the line integral of velocity field is called "flow" or "circulation."

Answer (score 0):

The heat equation in $3+1$ dimensions
$$\frac{∂ρ}{∂t} = α ∇^2ρ$$
with $ρ = ρ(,t)$ lifts to a hyperbolic equation-with-constraint in $4+1$ dimensions, as
$$\left(∇^2 + \frac{∂^2ρ}{∂t∂u}\right)ρ = 0, \quad \frac{∂ρ}{∂u} = -\frac{ρ}{α},$$
with solutions of the form $ρ(,t,u) = e^{-u/α} ρ(,t)$, where $ρ(,t) = ρ(,t,0)$.

The coordinate $u$ has the dimension of length-squared/time.

This may be seen, more explicitly, to be the wave-equation-with-constraint. Under the substitution:
$$t_± = t ± \frac{u}{V^2}, \quad \hat{ρ}\left(,t_+,t_-\right) = ρ(,t,u),$$
where $V$ is an arbitrarily-chosen non-zero speed, we have
$$\frac{∂ρ}{∂t} = \left(\frac{∂}{∂t_+} + \frac{∂}{∂t_-}\right)\hat{ρ}, \quad \frac{∂ρ}{∂u} = \frac{1}{V^2}\left(\frac{∂}{∂t_+} - \frac{∂}{∂t_-}\right)\hat{ρ},$$
resulting in the equations:
$$\left(V^2∇^2 + \left(\frac{∂}{∂t_+}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{∂}{∂t_-}\right)^2\right)\hat{ρ} = 0, \quad \frac{∂\hat{ρ}}{∂t_+} - \frac{∂\hat{ρ}}{∂t_-} = -V^2\frac{\hat{ρ}}{α},$$
with general solutions of the form
$$\hat{ρ}\left(,t_+,t_-\right) = e^{V^2\left(t_- - t_+\right)/(2α)} ρ\left(,\frac{t_+ + t_-}{2}\right), \quad ρ(,t) = \hat{ρ}\left(,t,t\right).$$